# How to store multiple instances of the plugin's options for various shortcodes

Tags: plugins, shortcode, options, plugin-options

I am so new in WordPress plugin development. I have a plugin options page that contains one text field and one button. So when a url is given to the text field and stored with the button, using a shortcode that url appears where the shortcode is located. It is working so far. But what if I want to save multiple urls and produce multiple shortcodes ?!

I can produce an interface that has something like a [new URL] button that when clicked a new form generates with a unique value for the shortcode. But how can I add it to the database, instead of replacing it with the previous one.

Basically in this question, I am expecting some clue to understand how to approach to this case. There are many gallery plugins that work the same way. Can someone please explain the idea how to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to create many objects, you can use a custom post type : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

Comment: Why not just use a shortcode attribute, eg. `[my_shortcode url="http://example.com/"]`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie well it is not possible in my case because I am looking for a solution such as the photo gallery plugins, that there is always a button in the plugin settings page to create a new gallery and choose pics and etc then show the gallery with its giver Shortcode.

Comment: Ass @mmm said, then you need a custom post type.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for your comment. [This](https://goo.gl/1JYQEf) is more like what I am looking for. Obviously this plugin is very extensive but the idea is similar to what I am looking for that it creates the objects using the options page. Any idea with that?

Comment: That's all achievable with a custom post type and custom fields. If you don't want it to be a post type, there's no shortcut. You'd need custom database tables and APIs. You'd essentially be dealing with raw PHP/MySQL at that point.